# Set ExpressionEngine admin message in custom add-on

Tags: expressionengine

How do I set an error/success message in the ExpressionEngine admin panel from a bespoke add-on I'm developing?

I have a form, and wish to send back the result (i.e. "Form submission as successful") in the area where messages usually appear in the admin panel. Example in screen-shot below:

[image: ExpressionAdmin admin message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS method $.ee_notice

```
$.ee_notice("Your success message", {type: "success", open: true});
```

OR

```
$.ee_notice("Your error message", {type: "error", open: true});
```

If you're doing a redirect after a form post, you can use set_flashdata prior to the redirect:

```
$this->EE->session->set_flashdata('message_success', 'Your success message');
$this->EE->functions->redirect($url);
```

OR

```
$this->EE->session->set_flashdata('message_failure', 'Your error message');
$this->EE->functions->redirect($url);
```

Comment: This solved it. I was doing the `set_flashdata` call but not redirecting. It works now I've stuck the `redirect` call in there. Thanks!